# What is the difference between session-timeout and max-age in web.xml?

Tags: servlets, cookies, web.xml, session-timeout

I am not sure if I understand:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> <!-- 30 minutes! -->
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <max-age>1800</max-age> <!-- 1800 seconds: 30 minutes! -->
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Also, is there any way to configure ALL cookies in web.xml? This seems to apply to session cookies only. Do I need a filter for such feature?

Comment: Cookie fields like max-age should be set by the creator of the cookie. Since this session cookie is created by the container, the container provides config for the fields. If a cookie is generated by your app, your app needs to set the proper field values.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Why do we even need this? Quoting the Servlet 3.0 specification:

> In the HTTP protocol, there is no explicit termination signal when a
>   client is no longer active. This means that the only mechanism that
>   can be used to indicate when a client is no longer active is a time
>   out period.

The web-commons schema really nails explaining it:

> The session-timeout element defines the default session timeout interval for all sessions created in this web application. The specified timeout must be expressed in a whole number of minutes.
>
> If the timeout is 0 or less, the container ensures the default behaviour of sessions is never to time out. 
>   If this element is not specified, the container must set its default
>   timeout period.

The web-commons schema also got something for us about the `max-age` element:

> The lifetime (in seconds) that will be assigned to any session tracking cookies created by this web application. Default is -1

And to answer your last question:

> Also, is there any way to configure ALL cookies in web.xml? This seems
>   to apply to session cookies only. Do I need a filter for such feature?

I don't think so. 
The easiest™ way to do so IMHO would be to subclass 
[`HttpServletResponseWrapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) overriding the `addCookie()` method.

So to sum it up:

- **session-timeout** configures how long the *session* will linger around consuming server resources, even when not being actively accessed.
- **max-age** configures how long the client browser will keep the *session cookie*. This setting only applies to the lifetime of the *cookie*: it won't do a thing if you're using URL rewriting, and it has absolutely nothing to do with how long the sessions are kept at the server-side. The default, -1, keeps the *cookie* for as long as the browser session is active.

---

#### Useful links:

Servlet 3.1 JSR-340 specification page:
http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html

The web-commons XSD is available at:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-common_3_0.xsd

Comment: So if my max-age for session cookie is less than my session-time-out, it is possible that the session will keep living in the web - app 's memory, but the client will not be sending the session cookie anymore?

Comment: @KorayTugay you cannot directly compare the two values, they measure different things (and I am not referring just to the different units). See my answer for more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40825334/274677

Answer (score 19):

Before explaining what they are be sure to understand a few things.

From your question it is clear you are already aware of the first but perhaps confused about the second item in the below list:

- the two settings use **different units**: `session-timeout` is in *minutes*, whereas `max-age` is in *seconds*
- they measure time in **different ways**: `session-timeout` measures time in a *relative* way, `max-age` measures time in an *absolute* way (explained further below)
- they are taken into account and enforced by different software components. The `session-timeout` is taken into account by the container, whereas the `max-age` is taken into account and enforced by the user's browser. Equivalently, you may say that `session-timeout` applies to the server-side, whereas `max-age` applies to the client side.

`session-timeout` gives the maximum **idle duration** before the container decides to destroy the *session object* representing your "connection" in the server. This means that you may set the value of `session-timeout` to just 1 minute and still manage to keep the session object in the server **forever** as long as your browser sends HTTP GET, POST etc. messages to the server once every 59 seconds.

`max-age` is used by the user's browser to compute an absolute, fixed point in time, beyond which the *session cookie* (`JSESSIONID` in Java) will no longer be sent to the server. The browser computes this fixed point in time based on the time when the server sent the cookie to the browser (plus `max-age`). This is an *absolute* fixed point in time beyond which the cookie will no longer be sent to the server. As such, **activity or inactivity on behalf of the user makes no difference**. That's why if you examine the cookies in the developer console of your browser you see an absolute timestamp for the session cookie:

[image]

#### Caveat

An exception to the above description on the value of `max-age` denoting a fixed point in time, is if the specially interpreted value `-1` is used. In such a case that's what you see in the developer console:

[image]

… and also as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35105738/274677) this means that the browser will keep sending the cookie for the duration of the "browser session". I am putting "browser session" in quotes to differentiate it from server-side sessions. How the concept of a session is understood by a browser (e.g. whether different tabs correspond to different sessions) is implementation-specific.

Given the different semantics of `session-timeout` and `max-age`, it follows that attempts to "align" the two values like the `web.xml` excerpt you provide in your question:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> <!-- 30 minutes! -->
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <max-age>1800</max-age> <!-- 1800 seconds: 30 minutes! -->
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

… likely indicate confusion.

`max-age` provides a hard limit (unless the special value `-1` is used), whereas `session-timeout` effectively provides no limit, as long as the user actively uses the session. This being said, I think it makes more sense that `max-age` is larger in value than `session-timeout` rather than the other way around.

Regarding the default and specially interpreted values (`0` for the `session-timeout` and `-1` for `max-age`) and whether you can configure those values for all cookies (as opposed to just the session cookie), these points are explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35105738/274677).

Comment: Wow, what a great answer, so clear and with lots of useful details.

Comment: Indeed a great answer. But this brings another question. Should we always align session-timeout and max-age values(that is 30 mins in the example above)? Is there any use case where they are different?

Comment: @theprogrammer updated the answer; hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

`<session-timeout>` is the maximum duration of unused session (from the time of the last request). When a session is not used (no request) for that amount of time, the server-side application kills the session (you can catch this event and implement your own behaviour ).

Session cookie `max-age` defines how long this cookie is stored in user browser.

To conculde, when a session cookie reaches his max-age, the session is forced to disconnect. In the other case, when a session is disconnected by `session-timemout` event, the session-cookie might still be present on user browser