# How can I reset the session timeout in a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, session

I have set the session timeout to 20 minutes by adding the following line to my `application.properties` file:

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=20m
```

The problem is that my application is a single page application. So even if I use it I never change page and the timeout is never reset. Therefore after 20 minutes I am logged out. I can I tell Spring to reset the timeout after each REST request?

Comment: You need to set the server's session timeout rather than cookie max age. This will reset on each interaction with the server. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105410/what-is-the-difference-between-session-timeout-and-max-age-in-web-xml

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing this line:

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=20m
```

with this line

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=20m
```

in the `application.properties` file.

Comment: hello, this solution works, but spring does not renew cookie automatically on request. So after 20 minutes (even its 20 minutes of activity), user will be logged out. Is there any property or "nice" solution to tell spring to renew (beside the session renew) cookie expiry on each request?