# Spring Boot session configuration questions

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

I have a Spring Boot application and I can't seem to get my login session to last very long. I'm setting the following in `application.properties`:

```
spring.session.timeout = 180d
server.servlet.session.timeout = 180d
```

I have a couple of questions:

• What duration suffixes are allowed when specifying `spring.session.timeout` and `server.servlet.session.timeout`? I can't find this documented anywhere, just a note in these [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#httpsession-rest) saying “If a duration suffix is not specified, seconds are used,” implying other durations are possible.

• Do I need to include `spring-session` in my POM? I don't care about session clustering or the stateful REST API support, and I want to avoid more startup time and configuration. I certainly don’t want to configure more persistence.

My primary concern is keeping me logged in to the website (ideally indefinitely).

I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.0-RELEASE.

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If your are not using Spring Session, you should use the property `server.servlet.session.timeout`.

When specifying the timeout you have 3 options.

- You can use the standard ISO-8601 format [used by java.time.Duratio](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api//java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-), for example `P180D` for 180 days.
- You can use a simple format where the value and the unit are coupled, for example `180d` for 180 days. You can find the supported units in [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-conversion-duration) of the Spring Boot reference docs.
- Finally, you can use a `long` representation and the specified number will be interpreted as second, for example `200` for 200 seconds.

You do not need to include `spring-session` in your POM.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring boot 2.4+. It might work in the below version but I did not test it.

I am using the below configuration. max-age sets the max-age in the cookie on the browser side and timeout sets the timeout in the MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL column in spring_session which I store in JDBC.

When I use only max-age, my cookie gets deleted from the backend database in 30 minutes.
When I use the only timeout, the cookie gets deleted from the browser on the browser restart.
Therefore, I have set max age to 30 days to persist the session in browser and timeout to 30 days to persist the session in db.

```
server:
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        max-age: 30d
      timeout: 30d
```

My build.gradle for oauth looks like

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    // for oauth
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

    // to store session in jdbc
    implementation "org.springframework.session:spring-session-jdbc"
```

[Helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105410/what-is-the-difference-between-session-timeout-and-max-age-in-web-xml#:%7E:text=session%2Dtimeout%20configures%20how%20long,will%20keep%20the%20session%20cookie.)