# Apply a different session duration according to the user's roles

Tags: spring-boot, session, tomcat, spring-security

I'm working on a SpringBoot application with an embedded Tomcat servlet container.

During the authentication workflow I would like to be able to define a **session timeout** accordingly to the **roles** of the user whose login-in.

For example an *admin* could have a session which would live for let's say 2 hours while a *regular user* would have a session duration of 1 hour.
After what the user would receive a **HTTP 401 response status** on his following requests to protected resources.

I'm currently using the `server.servlet.session.timeout` property but it only let me set this timeout value for everybody it's not individually configurable and that's not what I want.

I'm also aware of the `setMaxInactiveInterval` method available for the session but, correct me if I'm wrong, its purpose is to define the idle value between 2 requests after which it invalidates the session.
Again that's not what I want.

- Is there a way to programmatically define the duration of a user session on a case-by-case basis ?
- If not, how could I destroy / invalidate a session using a **cron job** (using a ScheduledFuture or whatever) ?
  I could create some cron logic by listening to `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` and invoke `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()` once the defined timeout is reached but I'm not sure it would invalidate the session.
  And I don't think I could invalidate it without having access to the session which can only be done through a request, right ?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit 1:** I think I misunderstood the usage of the `server.servlet.session.timeout` property, I thought it will kill the session after the specified time but it's more about the idle time between requests (more or less like the `setMaxInactiveInterval` method).

- So my third question would be : is there a way to specify the duration of a user session wether or not there is activity during this session (I can't find any property for this) ?

**Edit 2:** From what I understand from this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/40825334/11648839 maybe it would be interesting for me to work with the JSESSIONID cookie and its max-age value